# 16 bit binary leading zeros

Tags: java, binary, translate

I am using toBinaryString translation method like this:

```
for (i=0; i<anyLines.length; i++) {

            if (anyLines[i].startsWith("@")) {
                anyLines[i] = anyLines[i].replace("@","");
                anyLines[i] = Integer.toBinaryString((Integer.parseInt(anyLines[i])));
            }
            else {
                continue;
            }
```

But when I write to a file, the binary is only 2 bits long, though I want a 16 bit binary with all the zeros. For example, 2 is translated as 10, though I'd like to have 0000000000000010. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6):

Just add 2^17 and `substring` the whole string:

```
anyLines[i] = Integer.toBinaryString(131072 + (Integer.parseInt(anyLines[i]))).substring(1, 17);
```

Answer (score 2):

After you set the binary string just check the string length and append enough zeros to the front of the string to make it 16 chars long.

Comment: "append enough zeros to the front" - try the words "prepend" or "prefix" - appending to the front, is an oxymoron.